# How do I configure an application, not generated by jhipster, to send logs and metrics to jhipster console?

Tags: jhipster

[Jhipster Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyPBC.png)

I have tried copying the MetricsConfiguration, LoggingConfiguration and JhipsterProperties among other files along with their dependencies.

I am at a complete loss, any ideas or insight would be appreciated.

```
jhipster:
    security:
        rememberMe:
            # security key (this key should be unique for your application, and kept secret)
            key: #placeholder
    mail: # specific JHipster mail property, for standard properties see MailProperties
        from: jhipster@localhost
        baseUrl: http://127.0.0.1:8080
    metrics: # DropWizard Metrics configuration, used by MetricsConfiguration
        jmx.enabled: true
        graphite:
            enabled: false
            host: localhost
            port: 2003
            prefix: jhipster
        prometheus:
            enabled: false
            endpoint: /prometheusMetrics
        logs: # Reports Dropwizard metrics in the logs
            enabled: true
            reportFrequency: 60 # in seconds
    logging:
        logstash: # Forward logs to logstash over a socket, used by LoggingConfiguration
            enabled: true
            host: localhost
            port: 5000
            queueSize: 512
```

Comment: What you did seems correct. How do you know it does not work?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to copy the configuration I implemented in JHipster.

- First, you have to setup the logstash-logback-encoder to report to logstash. Have a look at the github project. You can set this up either in logback.xml or in java code similar to what I did in LoggingConfiguration.java.
- Then you have to setup dropwizard metrics to report metrics in the logs. Have a look at their documentation.
- Finally you might have to edit the logstash.conf file with the grok rules so that it fits your logs that might not have the exact same format than the one you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`LoggingConfiguration` uses 3 application properties: `spring.application.name`, `server.port` and `eureka.instance.instanceId`. You must make sure they are defined in your `application-*.yml` (or `bootstrap-*.yml` if your app is spring cloud app).